# writeFieldReport for nodal force

Tags: python, abaqus

Does anyone knows how to use writeFieldReport to export NFORC results into a text file?
Right now I am trying this for global nodal displacements:

```
session.writeFieldReport(fileName='DISPLACEMENT_OUT.rpt',
append=OFF,
sortItem='Node Label', 
odb=odb, 
step=last_step_number, 
frame=lastframe_number,
outputPosition=NODAL,
displayGroup= dg ,
variable=( ('U',NODAL), )
)
```

This will give me nodal displacement, I need to find element nodal forces using writeFieldReport. 
PS: I already know how to use probe value to get "NFORCE"s I need to find a way to automate the post processing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Analysis User's Manual>Output>Nodal Variables, the variable identifier you are looking for is probably one of: `TF`, `RF`, or `CF`. Details on these output variables and how to request them from an analysis are available in the manual, if you need them.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I ended up using this setting

    session.writeFieldReport(fileName='NFORC1_OUT.rpt',
  append=OFF,
  sortItem='Node Label', 
  odb=odb, 
  step=last_step_number, 
  frame=lastframe_number,
  outputPosition=ELEMENT_NODAL,
  displayGroup= dg ,
  variable=( ('NFORC1',ELEMENT_NODAL), )
  )